# Spark streaming application on a single virtual machine, standalone mode

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have created spark streaming application, which worked fine when deploy mode was client.

On my virtual machine I have master and only one worker.

When I tried to change mode to "cluster" it fails. In web UI, I see that the driver is running, but application is failed.

**EDITED**

In the log, I see following content:

> 16/03/23 09:06:25 INFO Master: Driver submitted org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper
>
> 16/03/23 09:06:25 INFO Master: Launching driver driver-20160323090625-0001 on worker worker-20160323085541-10.0.2.15-36648
>
> 16/03/23 09:06:32 INFO Master: metering.dev.enerbyte.com:37168 got disassociated, removing it.
>
> 16/03/23 09:06:32 INFO Master: 10.0.2.15:59942 got disassociated, removing it.
>
> 16/03/23 09:06:32 INFO Master: metering.dev.enerbyte.com:37166 got disassociated, removing it.
>
> 16/03/23 09:06:46 INFO Master: Registering app wibeee-pipeline
>
> 16/03/23 09:06:46 INFO Master: Registered app wibeee-pipeline with ID app-20160323090646-0007
>
> 16/03/23 09:06:46 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20160323090646-0007/0 on worker worker-20160323085541-10.0.2.15-36648
>
> 16/03/23 09:06:50 INFO Master: Received unregister request from application app-20160323090646-0007
>
> 16/03/23 09:06:50 INFO Master: Removing app app-20160323090646-0007
>
> 16/03/23 09:06:50 WARN Master: Got status update for unknown executor app-20160323090646-0007/0
>
> 16/03/23 09:06:50 INFO Master: metering.dev.enerbyte.com:37172 got disassociated, removing it.
>
> 16/03/23 09:06:50 INFO Master: 10.0.2.15:45079 got disassociated, removing it.
>
> 16/03/23 09:06:51 INFO Master: Removing driver: driver-20160323090625-0001

So what happens is that master launches the driver on the worker,application gets registered, and then executir is tried to be launched on the same worker, which fails (although I have only one worker!)

**EDIT**
Can the issue be related to the fact that I use checkpointing, because I have "updateStateByKey" transformation in my code. It is set to "/tmp", but I always get a warning that "when run in cluster mode, "/tmp" needs to change. How should I set it?

Can that be the reason of my problem?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is the error message? It can be anything ranging from network access issues to a problem in the cluster reference you use.

Comment: Are you using properties file?

Comment: @Akira I have edited the question placing content from the spark/log directory.

Comment: @anupsth Yes, I use properties file

Answer (score 0):

According to log you have provided, it may not because of properties file but check this.

`spark-submit` only copies jar file to driver when running in cluster mode, so if your application tries to read properties file kept in the system from where you are running spark-submit,  driver can not find it when running in cluster mode.

reading from properties file works in client mode because driver starts at the same machine where your are executing spark-submit.

You can copy properties to same directory in all nodes or keep properties file in cassandra file system and read from there.